# How to use grep for such case?

Tags: grep

grep function not working in the correct manner.

## Here is my code:

```
echo -n "Title: "                        # prompt user for title
read title                               # get input from keyboard
echo -n "Author: "                       # prompt user for author
read author                              # get input from keyboard

if grep -q -i -w $title BookDB.txt       # check for title in BookDB.txt
  then                                     # if duplicate exist
    clear                                  # clear screen
    echo "Error! Book already exists!"     # prompt user about duplicated entry
    echo " "                               # newline
    continue                               # display main menu
  else                                     # if duplicate absent
    echo -n "Price: "                      # prompt user for price
    read price                             # get input from keyboard
    echo -n "Qty Available: "              # prompt user for qty available
    read qtyAvail                          # get input from keyboard
    echo -n "Qty Sold: "                   # prompt user for qty sold
    read qtySold                           # get input from keyboard
```

## E.g

"Lord of the ring" is in the BookDB.txt

If I want to add new book, will check if it exists a not.

However, if I want to add "Lord of the Stone", it says that already exist.
Advise please.

Comment: 5 lines is the point where I give up with bash and write in a proper language, such as Python.

Answer (score 2):

Always quote your shell variables:

```
if grep -q -i -w "$title" BookDB.txt
```

Otherwise, shell interprets each part separated by whitespace as a different argument. For grep this means search "Lord" in files named `of`, `the`, `Stone`, and `BookDB.txt`.

Comment: thanks for the speedy response!
if i want to remove the title of a book in BookDB.txt, other than "sed -d", is there other simple code to remove?

I'm still learning shell script. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Minimal solution:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo -n "Title: "                        # prompt user for title
read title                               # get input from keyboard
if grep -q -i -w "$title" BookDB.txt ;  then 
   echo "Found"
else
   echo "do something else"
fi
```

Try with and without the quoted `$title` to see the effect.

Also note this will partial match, so "Lord" will find "Lord of the Rings" and "Lord Of The Flies". But you have bigger problems ahead of you...